# Scrapy Disqus API Request Fails

Tags: python, api, request, scrapy, disqus

Currently I try to scrape comment data from diverse websites. Since many seem to use Disqus for their comment section I have to query some of the comments from the Disqus API.
Since the remaining project is implemented in Python with Scrapy I wanted to integrate the API access as well.

```py
def parse(self, response):
    article_id = response.meta['external_id']

    request_url = self.disqus_api \
                  + "threads/" \
                  + "details" \
                  + "?" + "thread=ident:" + str(article_id) \
                  + "&forum=" + self.forum \
                  + "&api_key=" + str(self.getApiKey())

    request = Request(request_url, callback=self.obtain_thread_ID, errback=self.error_back)

    return request
```

However, whenever I run the Spider containing this code, it will always enter the `errback`-callback.
First I assumed it might be due to an invalid request. So I debugged the code with PyCharm to obtain the `request_url` (which for example looks like this: 'http://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/details?thread=ident:155194734&forum=welt&api_key=insert_your_api_key_here').

So I opened up a command line and executed a `scrapy shell request_url`. Doing this I get back a valid response containing the JSON data I need. This now confuses me, since I fail to understand why I can request the JSON via `scrapy shell` or via `curl` or a Browser but not with the Scrapy spider.

Has someone an idea what the issue might be? I would also be happy to get some workarounds that are not too "ugly".

**EDIT:**

I was able to investigate the issue further. When I read out the values send to `self.error_back`, the following is returned: `<400 http://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/details?thread=ident:155194734&forum=welt&api_key=insert_your_api_key_here>`.
This obviously tells me that something should be wrong with my API request. However if I click on the URL displayed in the PyCharm terminal, my browser pops up and immediately shows me a correctly formatted JSON response. If I compare the URLs shown in the PyCharm terminal and the one used in the browser, both are equal. While I am always happy to figure out a potential source of error, this case continues to confuse me: How is it possible that a Scrapy request returns a Code 400 and a browser request a Code 200?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. When I try with any other JSON returning website it works just fine. Probably related to the website itself. You should try with a different user-agent

Comment: Try to yield the request instead of returning

Comment: Shame that scrapy does not keep the status line text, only status code. [400 can mean a few things for disqus API](https://disqus.com/api/docs/errors/). If you can sniff the network traffic (with Wireshark or tcpdump), you could get more information. Actually, the response body contains information it seems: _"Every error is represented with an HTTP status code, as well as a code and response message within the actual response body."_

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida: Thanks for the feedback. Actually using `yield` instead of `return` looks more promising. In some cases the API access even succeeds - however in most cases it still fails.

But interestingly the `yield` approach returns the status lines @paultrmbrth mentioned. The status code is 400-11 which according to the Disqus API Doc indicates a non-suitable API key.

Comment: This, however, I think is quite unlikely. Because if I hit the very same URL/API-Request-URL with my browsers (Chrome and Firefox) I get an immediate JSON return.

Also a simple `request = urllib2.urlopen(request_url)` followed by `raw_json = request.read()` nearly always returns the correct result (except some random timeouts).

So while I will check the Wireshark method later to actually find out more about what is going wrong, for the moment I am afraid I have to go with the `urllib2` variant since it seems to work best.

Comment: @MarcoN. In your settings.py file change the user-agent to your browser's one, on mine it is something like this
`USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida, again thank you for your feedback. However. even changing that unfortunately does not resolve the situation. I even tried the user-agents of both, Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. Yet, the return is `{"code":11,"response":"Your API key is not valid on this domain"}`.

Comment: Make a print of your request_url before requesting it